# Intel Wireless-AC 9560 disconnecting from AP

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-11

I have had this problem since Windows 10 and now on a clean install of Windows 11 Pro 64bit it still happening where every time I connect to an AP WIFI would disconnect and reconnect all by itself cause Intel_PIE_Service.exe (PIEServiceNew)

why is this happening and how I can fix it?

Device: Asus GL504GW
WIFI: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz (Driver ver: 22.90.0.5)
OS: Windows 11 Pro 64bit 21H2 (10.0.22000)

Comment: Did you try updating firmware on your Access Point?

Comment: @John my AP is an Android 11 phone with the latest patch I don't think it's that cause this situation only happens when PIEServiceNew service gets created